# How to Automatically Build And Deploy to Multiple Android Devices in Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx, multiplayer

I'm building a multiplayer game on **Android** and my iteration cycle is very manual.

1. Build & Run Android, Choose Device, Select Device A
2. Build & Run Android, Choose Device, Select Device B
   etc.

Is there a way with one click, to build android, and deploy to multiple connected devices over **USB**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see the list of devices come up after launching the app, just shift or control click each device you want it to launch on.

Like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Device Chooser menu, you can select multiple devices (with shift click) and it will deploy to them in one go.